# Creating vector files programmatically?

Tags: php, javascript, flash, apache-flex, vector

Is there a way to create vector files programmatically?  The company I'm working for has to deliver vector assets to our clients (which are originally designed in flash, then the elements positions,scale and other details are stores in the database), and we want to eliminate the need for a human to actually create the vector graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SVG**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) is an open XML vector format you can easily create with any XML library. Have a look at the [SVG Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#examples).

Comment: Can you create layers in an SVG file? We need to seperate out the colors for our clients into different layers!

Comment: @Walker Yup, that's absolutely no problem. Just use the `<g>` element. Feel free to experiment with inkscape and either inspect the saved files or select `Edit -> XML Editor ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). It's XML-based, so tweaking positions and colors is just a matter of tweaking the `pos=` attribute of an XML element.

There aren't any SVG libraries for PHP that I am aware of, but creating a SVG image is just like creating an XML document, so using `SimpleXML` or a similar library should suffice.

Here's an example script that performs serverside SVG creation: http://www.carto.net/svg/samples/serverside_svg_php.shtml

Comment: Can you convert SVG into eps or ai files for delivery?  Or will most clients familiar with vector be able to open SVG?

Comment: Yes, you can. If your server environment is running Linux (Windows will work too), you can just install ImageMagick and it will convert the file. BTW, isn't EPS a raster format?

Comment: @Blender No, EPS supports both raster and vector graphics. Since inkscape tends to perform better with raster than vector graphics, you may prefer [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). It's mainly a graphical program, but can also be [used on the command line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inkscape), to export to EPS (among other formats).

Comment: One last question:  Can you create layers in an SVG file?  We need to seperate out the colors for our clients into different layers!

Comment: No, not really. You could create separate SVGs for each color (you can even program that functionality), though, and merge them for a final image.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to SVG: if your client specifically wanted files in Flash format, Flash also have an .xfl format - http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=1986 - which is essentially an uncompressed fla.

It compromises a folder with a number of easily created sub folders, where all shapes/movieclips etc are xml based.

Provided they have CS5 (I have CS5, not sure if it's available below that) or above, they'll be able to open it no problem.

Create a new fla and save it as .xfl to see the layout.